# Spring Data JPA @Modifying annotation usage with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-data

I am new in `Spring Data JPA` and will use `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)` annotation for an update method that updated a name field of Product entity. I have 2 questions that made me confused:

**1.** Do we need to use `@Transactional` with `@Modifying` annotation?

**2.** What does `@Modifying` exactly do? I read several pages e.g. [Spring Data JPA @Modifying Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation), and now too confused.

Comment: Does anybody else has never used `@Modifying()` ever before???

Comment: Any reply please?

Answer (score 1):

Second question first: the Modifying annotation lets you execute  DML (inserts, updates, deletes) and DDL using JPA Query annotations where you put the DML or DDL where the query would normally go.

To answer the first question, i would expect to use this in a service layer annotated with @Transactional instead of putting the annotation on the Repository, because these operations seem likely to occur as part of a bigger operation with other business logic.  But if that is not the case then the annotation could go on the Repository.

Comment: Thanks  a lot, voted up. In this scene, if we use a **custom** query (JPQL for example) to make inserts, updates, deletes, then we will use `@Modifying`. Is that true?